# Add content block to footer

Tags: theme, magento2.2.2, footer, footer-links

I would like to add some content to the footer.

[image]

I followed few tutorials and was able to edit (remove some and add some others) default footer links by editing the file:

```
website-root/app/design/frontend/MJ/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

And I was able to add extra content to footer from:

```
Admin: Content > Blocks > Add New Block
```

and then reference that block from a Widget. The Widget was set up to appear in the container: `Page Footer`

[image]

and it showed to right under subscribe button as seen in the image above.

I tried changing the container to `Page Footer Container`

[image]

but it showed just under existing links.

[image]

I still have a lot to learn while customizing this theme, therefore, I would appreciate any insights you could provide into how to handle this in Magento.

Answer (score 3):

Remove Default Footer in default.xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
```

And also Add following code in default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container">
           <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer_block" as="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

And add static block in your theme file footer.phtml

```
$block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up removing the footer and making footer HTML as a Content Block and styled it with CSS.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid please add your solution as an answer and accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove default links:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
```

And put your block into this:

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">              
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="custom_links" before="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom_links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>            
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up removing the footer and making footer HTML as a Content Block and styled it with CSS.